# How to display categories which contains particular tag?

Tags: categories, tags

I want to display a list of categories which contains particular tag. E.g. The categories from the tag "Computer"

I have checked    `get_categories();` method but it is not working for me.

What should I do?

Comment: Categories do not contain tags, those are two different taxonomies. Please explain your problem better. :)

Comment: So you want to: Load all posts with that tag -> load all categories that those posts belong to and list them?